# Swift : Thread 10: Fatal error: unableToParse

Tags: swift, api, parsing

I've been using [NewsApi](https://newsapi.org/) . and it works perfectly but all of a sudden I got this error :

> Thread 10: Fatal error: unableToParse

is anyone familiar with this error

my view controller :

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource ,UIScrollViewDelegate , UITabBarDelegate {



    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    var i: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var bookMark: UITabBarItem!


    // outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var articles = [NewsArticle]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    let newsAPI = NewsAPI(apiKey: "//////////")

    private let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))


    //// table View
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FeaturesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FeaturesTableViewCell


            return cell

        }
       else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            var breakingNews : String = ""

            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BreakingNewsViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! BreakingNewsViewCell
            for article in articles
            {

                breakingNews = breakingNews+" - "+article.title


            }
            cell.newsLabel.text = breakingNews
            return cell


        }
        else{
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NewViewCellTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! NewViewCellTableViewCell

            cell.titleLabel.text = "NEWS"

            return cell
        }


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        newsAPI.getTopHeadlines(q:"a"){ result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let articles):
                self.articles = articles
            case .failure(let error):
                fatalError("\(error)")
            }
        }

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

       // setupMenuBar()
    }


}
```

and i got that error marked in :

```
case .failure(let error):
```

but it used work perfectly

NewsApi Class:

```
public typealias NewsAPIRequestHandler<T> = ((Result<[T], NewsAPIError>) -> ())

public class NewsAPI {
    private let provider: NewsProvider
    private let decoder: NewsAPIDecoder

    public init(apiKey: String) {
        self.provider = NewsProvider(apiKey: apiKey)
        self.decoder = NewsAPIDecoder()
    }

    init(provider: NewsProvider, sourceDecoder: NewsAPIDecoder) {
        self.provider = provider
        self.decoder = sourceDecoder
    }

    @discardableResult
    public func getSources(category: NewsCategory = .all, language: NewsLanguage = .all, country: NewsCountry = .all, completion: @escaping NewsAPIRequestHandler<NewsSource>) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
        let targetAPI = NewsAPITarget.sources(category: category, language: language, country: country)
        return request(targetAPI, completion: completion)
    }

    @discardableResult
    public func getTopHeadlines(q: String? = nil,
                                sources: [String]? = nil,
                                category: NewsCategory = .all,
                                language: NewsLanguage = .all,
                                country: NewsCountry = .all,
                                pageSize: Int? = nil,
                                page: Int? = nil,
                                completion: @escaping NewsAPIRequestHandler<NewsArticle>) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
        let targetAPI = NewsAPITarget.topHeadlines(q: q, sources: sources, category: category, language: language, country: country, pageSize: pageSize, page: page)
        return request(targetAPI, completion: completion)
    }
}

private extension NewsAPI {
    func request<T: Decodable>(_ target: NewsAPITarget, completion: @escaping NewsAPIRequestHandler<T>) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
        return provider.request(target) { data, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(error ?? .unknown))
                return
            }

            do {
                let result: [T] = try self.decoder.decode(data: data)
                completion(.success(result))
            } catch let error {
                let newsAPIError = (error as? NewsAPIError) ?? .unknown
                completion(.failure(newsAPIError))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and as for newsAPIError class it has :

```
public enum NewsAPIError: Error {
    case unknown
    case unableToParse
    case requestFailed
    case invalidEndpointUrl
    case serviceError(code: String, message: String)
}
```

please any help is welcome and thank you

Comment: Show your code so we can help debug

Comment: @MobileMon i added my controller

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not related to the error. Most likely the `NewsArticle` struct doesn't match the received data. Doesn't the API provide a more specific error message?

Comment: @vadian i didn't find this error  unfortunately

Comment: Try to print the `error` without string interpolation: Replace `fatalError("\(error)")` with `print(error)`

Comment: @vadian  i get "unableToParse"

Comment: I assume the json parsing is done in the NewsAPI class, perhaps you could add that code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i added it

Comment: I recommend to contact the [developer](https://github.com/lucaslimapoa/NewsAPISwift) of NewsAPI and open an issue. Or could it be that your daily request limit is exceeded?

Comment: In the `request` function either print `error` or send it without casting to the completion handler, maybe it will contain a more detailed error message

Comment: @vadian it's working now but i sent the developer the issue so it can be clear thank you :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i will try it if the error is back because it started working again